# Need regular expression expertise

Tags: java, regex

I need help figuring out a regular expression for the rule:

> 6 characters, starting with letter R (uppercase), and followed by digits where at least one digit is not 0.

My attempt so far is `"[R][0-9]{5}[1-9]+"` but I keep getting a false when it should be returning true for R01001.  I'm stumped,  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^R(?=0*[1-9])[0-9]{5}$
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/bA7yI9

**Explanation:**

[image]